# How to go through each bit of a byte

Tags: c, algorithm

I do not not know how to implement the following algorithm.

For example I have int=26, this is "11010" in binary.
Now I need to implement one operation for 1, another for 0, from left to right, till the end of byte.
But I really have no idea how to implement this.
Maybe I can convert binary to char array, but I do not know how.
btw, int equals 26 only in the example, in the application it will be random.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224799/bitwise-flags-abandoned

Answer (score 9):

Since you want to move from 'left to right':

```
unsigned char val = 26;  // or whatever

unsigned int mask;

for (mask = 0x80; mask != 0; mask >>= 1) {

    if (val & mask) {
        // bit is 1
    }
    else {
        // bit is 0
    }
}
```

The `for` loop just walks thorough each bit in a byte, from the most significant bit to the least.

Comment: I can't understand why val is unsigned char?

Comment: And mask, I dont know, how long will be this value. I generate it random.

Comment: I used `unsigned char` because you indicated you were interested in performing an operation on each bit "till the end of byte". If you're interested in an object that's larger than a byte then use the appropriate type, but you'll need to change the starting bit in the `mask`. Note: `mask` is *not* random - it tracks the bit being examined at each step. If you want the value you're checking the bits of to be random, that's fine. Set it to whatever, however, you want. I used `26` in the example because that's what you used in your example. Set to whatever data you need for your application.

Comment: You said you wanted to go through each bit of a byte; a char is one byte.  If you want to go through each bit of an int, you could do that instead (but using a different start mask, as prev. comment says).

Comment: It might be a bit more self-documenting to initialize `mask=1<<7` instead of `mask=0x80`.  Comparably, for an int, you would start out with `mask=1<<31`, to begin at the most significant bit, or `mask=1<<7` if you want to begin at the most significant bit of the least significant byte.

Answer (score 5):

You can use modulo arithmetic or bitmasking to get what you need.

Modulo arithmetic:

```
int x = 0b100101;
// First bit
(x >> 0) % 2; // 1
// Second bit
(x >> 1) % 2; // 0
// Third bit
(x >> 2) % 2; // 1
...
etc.
```

Bitmasking

```
int x = 0b100101;
int mask = 0x01;
// First bit 
((mask << 0) & x) ? 1 : 0
// Second bit
((mask << 1) & x) ? 1 : 0
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this option:

```
isBitSet = ((bits & 1) == 1);
bits = bits >> 1
```

I find the answer also in stackoverflow:

[How do I properly loop through and print bits of an Int, Long, Float, or BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315650/how-do-i-properly-loop-through-and-print-bits-of-an-int-long-float-or-biginte)

Answer (score 3):

In C, C++, and similarly-syntaxed languages, you can determine if the right-most bit in an integer `i` is 1 or 0 by examining whether `i & 1` is nonzero or zero.  (Note that that's a single `&` signifying a bitwise AND operation, not a `&&` signifying logical AND.)  For the second-to-the-right bit, you check `i & 2`; for the third you check `i & 4`, and so on by powers of two.

More generally, to determine if the bit that's `j`th from the right is zero, you can check whether `i & (1 << (j-1)) != 0`.  The `<<` indicates a left-shift; `1 << (j-1)` is essentially equivalent to 2<sup>j-1</sup>.

Thus, for a 32-bit integer, your loop would look something like this:

```
unsigned int i = 26;  /* Replace this with however it's actually defined.  */

int j;
for (j = 31; j >= 0; j--)
{
  if ((i & (1 << (j-1))) != 0)
    /* do something for jth bit is 1 */
  else
    /* do something for jth bit is 0 */
}
```

Hopefully, that's enough to get you started.

Comment: It's not the constant 26, it was only for example.

Comment: I should have been clearer -- I was assigning "i = 26" in my code as an example following your example; I would assume you would define it some other way.  I'll clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Came across a similar problem so thought I'd share my solution. This is assuming your value is always one byte (8 bits)

Iterate over all 8 bits within the byte and check if that bit is set (you can do this by shifting the bit we are checking to the LSB position and masking it with `0x01`)

```
int value = 26;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if ((value >> i) & 0x01) {
        // Bit i is 1
        printf("%d is set\n", i);
    }
    else {
        // Bit i is 0
        printf("%d is cleared\n", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you say you want to do. You could probably use bitmasks to do any bit-manipulation in your byte, if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Hi
Look up bit shifting and bitwise and.