# Iterate bits from left to right for any number

Tags: c, rsa, traversal, exponentiation

I am trying to implement Modular Exponentiation (square and multiply left to right) algorithm in `c`.

In order to iterate the bits from left to right, I can use masking which is explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465488/how-to-go-through-each-bit-of-a-byte)
In this example mask used is `0x80` which can work only for a number with max `8 bits`.

In order to make it work for any number of bits, I need to assign mask dynamically but this makes it a bit complicated.

Is there any other solution by which it can be done.

Thanks in advance!

-------------EDIT-----------------------

```
    long long base = 23;
    long long exponent = 297;
    long long mod = 327;

    long long result = 1;

    unsigned int mask;

    for (mask = 0x80; mask != 0; mask >>= 1) {

         result = (result * result) % mod;  // Square

         if (exponent & mask) {
            result = (base * result) % mod; // Mul
         }
    }
```

As in this example, it will not work if I will use mask `0x80` but if I use `0x100` then it works fine. 
Selecting the mask value at run time seems to be an overhead.

Comment: Which part of it is complicated?  What have you tried?

Comment: Define maximal number, like `size_t` is your maximal value you will proceed. Then, to get mask, use `size_t mask = ((size_t)1 << (sizeof(size_t) * 8 - 1))`. Later, to traverse your number, use `size_t mynum = (size_t)input_number` and that's it. I assume you use unsigned numbers only.

Comment: @GauravPathak What is the actual problem?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth added the code which I have tried

Comment: @GauravPathak I don't understand, what is here complicated?

Comment: @tilz0R this method is actually unsafe. 1.) `CHAR_BIT` can be a bigger value than `8` 2.) even when using `CHAR_BIT`, the calculation could go wrong if your type has padding bits. -- for a correct solution to calculate the number of bits [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2371524).

Comment: @FelixPalmen What is `CHAR_BIT` in this case?

Comment: @tilz0R `CHAR_BIT` is defined in `limits.h` to the number of bits in a byte (aka `char`). Its very often `8`, but can be bigger.

Comment: @FelixPalmen You really think, that char may be bigger than 8-bits in C?

Comment: @tilz0R You really think it can't? Hint: read the standard. And yes, there are actual machines with bytes wider than 8 bits.

Comment: Then multiply by `8` change to `CHAR_BIT` and problem is solved.

Comment: @tilz0R no, it isn't, because of possible padding bits. See my answer.

Comment: If you used a right-to-left algorithm, you wouldn't need to worry about initializing the mask to a suitably large value.

Comment: @IanAbbott Agree, but in my case I need left-to-right algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to iterate over all bits, you first have to know how many bits there are in your type.

This is a surprisingly complicated matter:

- `sizeof` gives you the number of bytes, but a byte *can* have more than 8 bits.
- `limits.h` gives you `CHAR_BIT` to know the number of bits in a byte, but even if you multiply this by the `sizeof` your type, the result could still be wrong because unsigned types are allowed to contain *padding bits* that are not part of the number representation, while `sizeof` returns the *storage size* in bytes, which includes these *padding bits*.

Fortunately, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2371524) has an ingenious macro that can calculate the number of *actual value bits* based on the maximum value of the respective type:

```
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m) /((m)%0x3fffffffL+1) /0x3fffffffL %0x3fffffffL *30 \
                  + (m)%0x3fffffffL /((m)%31+1)/31%31*5 + 4-12/((m)%31+3))
```

The maximum value of an unsigned type is surprisingly easy to get: just cast `-1` to your unsigned type.

So, all in all, your code could look like this, including the macro above:

```
#define UNSIGNED_BITS IMAX_BITS((unsigned)-1)

// [...]

unsigned int mask;
for (mask = 1 << (UNSIGNED_BITS-1); mask != 0; mask >>= 1) {
    // [...]
}
```

Note that applying this complicated macro has no runtime drawback at all, it's a compile-time constant.

Comment: Interesting link, but since the bit-shifting operators work on values, not underlying representations, the padding bits are irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidBowling the operators work on values and this is the reason WHY the padding bits are very relevant. Using `sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT` would give you the storage size, *including* padding bits, so if there are padding bits, doing `1 << (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1)` would trigger undefined behavior, it shifts too far. The macro is for determining the number of actual value bits.

Comment: @DavidBowling still a good comment because now, I see how one could misread my answer. I'll improve the wording.

Comment: Well, I should have read more carefully, but your change does make the issue more clear. Already upvoted. The link is nice, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm seems unnecessarily complicated: bits from the exponent can be tested from the least significant to the most significant in a way that does not depend on the integer type nor its maximum value.  Here is a simple implementation that does not need any special case for any size integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long long base     = (argc > 1) ? strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 23;
    unsigned long long exponent = (argc > 2) ? strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0) : 297;
    unsigned long long mod      = (argc > 3) ? strtoull(argv[3], NULL, 0) : 327;
    unsigned long long y = exponent;
    unsigned long long x = base;
    unsigned long long result = 1;

    for (;;) {
        if (y & 1) {
            result = result * x % mod;
        }
        if ((y >>= 1) == 0)
            break;
        x = x * x % mod;
    }
    printf("expmod(%llu, %llu, %llu) = %llu\n", base, exponent, mod, result);
    return 0;
}
```

Without any command line arguments, it produces: `expmod(23, 297, 327) = 185`.  You can try other numbers by passing the base, exponent and modulo as command line arguments.

**EDIT:**

If you must scan the bits in `exponent` from most significant to least significant, `mask` should be defined as the same type as `exponent` and initialized this way if the type is unsigned:

```
 unsigned long long exponent = 297;
 unsigned long long mask = 0;
 mask = ~mask - (~mask >> 1);
```

If the type is signed, for complete portability, you must use the definition for its maximum value from `<limits.h>`.  Note however that it would be more efficient to use the unsigned type.

```
 long long exponent = 297;
 long long mask = LLONG_MAX - (LLONG_MAX >> 1);
```

The loop will waste time running through all the most significant `0` bits, so a simpler loop could be used first to skip these bits:

```
 while (mask > exponent) {
     mask >>= 1;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is the `right to left` implementation of the algorithm. In my case the requirement is implementing the algorithm from `left to right`.